# HOST NOT RESOLVABLE seen ONLY for FIRST request with RemoteWebDriver

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, firefox

HOST NOT RESOLVABLE seen ONLY for FIRST request with selenium-server-standalone 2.41(Machine A) RemoteWebDriver, Firefox 28 on Machine B alone with hub and node on the same MACHINE B.

The debugging session is going on from two days with no concrete outcome. Can anyone please point us in the right direction?

Are we missing anything as part of setup here? What is the ***correct way*** to make use of selenium-server-standalone 2.41 with Firefox 28 for RemoteWebDriver usecase?

### Maven Dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server-standalone</artifactId>
            <version>2.41.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

### SETUP AND EXECUTION DETAILS

We have two machines Machine A (ARM64) , Machine B(Linux X86).

The way we are making use of it now is as follows,

1. Machine A(Linux ARM64) is where RemoteWebDriver invocation occurs, selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar is used.
2. Machine B(Linux x86), we have a running docker container acts as both hub and node, Expose 4444 port from CONTAINER to HOST MACHINE B

```
 java -jar /u01/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -role hub

 java -jar /u01/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
```

3. Access the HOST:port from ARM based machine

***OUTPUT SEEN***

First connection results in WebDriver Exception, HOST NOT RESOLVABLE, however, subsequent connetions results in no expections, everything just works after first request failure. Here, Geckodriver is not used as we are making use of selenium 2.41, as per MOZ documention

```
https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html
```

CODE USED

The below code is executed from MACHINE A.

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://<<MACHINEB>>:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://localhost:4444");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue here is not with your Selenium code rather with the server you are calling. Probably it is initially "sleeping" and "wakes up" after it detects some request coming to it.

Comment: is there way to find that out?

Comment: To find out what?

Comment: as you have mentioned above "Probably it is initially "sleeping" and "wakes up" after it detects some request coming to it" 

is there a way to find this out?

Comment: In case this is the web site of your company - ask backend developers. Otherwise - send some API call to that server after a long time server was not used.